# Crashing From Light Multitasking - This can't be normal right?

Tags: 20.04, nvidia, chromium, obs-studio

I would love help to further troubleshoot this. (ubuntu 20.04, nvdia 2070S)

Processor: Intel i9-9900K (16) @ 5.000GHz

I experience crashes from various programs when doing even light multitasking. It looks different for each program, but for instance chrome tabs start to crash with a sigsegv error, discord suddenly restarts, etc.

I have been able to recreate this issue on a fresh install of popOS

However I haven't been able to replicate this issue in a windows installation on a different drive

I have reinstalled ubuntu several times already. Can anyone give me advice here?

**EDIT (output from ubuntu-drivers devices)**

sudo ubuntu-drivers devices

WARNING:root:_pkg_get_support nvidia-driver-510-server: package has invalid Support PBheader, cannot determine support level

WARNING:root:_pkg_get_support nvidia-driver-510: package has invalid Support PBheader, cannot determine support level
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.1/0000:02:00.0 ==

modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001E84sv00003842sd00003071bc03sc00i00

vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation

model    : TU104 [GeForce RTX 2070 SUPER]

driver   : nvidia-driver-470-server - distro non-free

driver   : nvidia-driver-510-server - distro non-free

driver   : nvidia-driver-470 - distro non-free recommended

driver   : nvidia-driver-450-server - distro non-free

driver   : nvidia-driver-510 - distro non-free

driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin

**Output from lspci**

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 8th Gen Core 8-core Desktop Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers [Coffee Lake S] (rev 0d)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 0d)
00:01.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x8) (rev 0d)
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Thermal Controller (rev 10)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 10)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Shared SRAM (rev 10)
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak] (rev 10)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH HECI Controller (rev 10)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SATA AHCI Controller (rev 10)
00:1b.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #17 (rev f0)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f0)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #2 (rev f0)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f0)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Z390 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller (rev 10)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS (rev 10)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SMBus Controller (rev 10)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SPI Controller (rev 10)
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (7) I219-V (rev 10)
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU104 [GeForce RTX 2070 SUPER] (rev a1)
02:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation TU104 HD Audio Controller (rev a1)
02:00.2 USB controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU104 USB 3.1 Host Controller (rev a1)
02:00.3 Serial bus controller [0c80]: NVIDIA Corporation TU104 USB Type-C UCSI Controller (rev a1)
03:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981/PM983
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I211 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03)
```

Comment: you are using ubuntu not popos right?

Comment: run `sudo ubuntu-drivers devices` and edit in what it outputs

Comment: Edited and added @lnee
Using Ubuntu

Comment: try `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-470`

Comment: @lnee When I run it it says I already have it 
nvidia-driver-470 is already the newest version (470.103.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 138 not upgraded.

Comment: ok do `lspci` and edit the out in your answer

Comment: @lnee Added output

Comment: Edit your question and tell me what processor you have. Also show me `ls -al /var/crash` and `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema Also added processor to question. These stats after after a reboot lmk if that's fine



`➜  ~ free -h

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available

Mem:           31Gi       2.2Gi        27Gi        54Mi       2.0Gi        28Gi

Swap:         2.0Gi          0B       2.0Gi
`
➜  ~ sysctl vm.swappiness

vm.swappiness = 60`

Comment: @heynnema
`ls -al /var/crash
total 367300
drwxrwsrwt  2 root   whoopsie    4096 Mar 31 20:47
drwxr-xr-x 15 root   root          4096 Oct 18 15:02 
-rw-r-----  1 NAME whoopsie 303306203 Mar 31 20:48 _usr_bin_obs.1000.crash
-rw-r-----  1 NAME whoopsie   6042584 Mar 25 18:37 _usr_lib_obs-plugins_obs-browser-page.1000.crash
-rw-r-----  1 root   whoopsie   3127280 Mar 26 12:48 _usr_lib_packagekit_packagekitd.0.crash
-rw-r-----  1 root   whoopsie    743129 Mar 24 19:30 _usr_lib_systemd_systemd.0.crash
-rw-r-----  1 NAME whoopsie  62871523 Mar 31 16:59 _usr_share_discord_Discord.1000.crash`

Comment: Sounds like a possible memory problem. Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take a few hours to complete. Report back.

Comment: Another possibility is an older BIOS. Do `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and tell me the EXACT make/model # of your computer or motherboard.

Comment: @heynnema Funny you suggested that. Already had started a memtest. Will return when finished :)

Comment: @heynnema I am still stress testing it but it did appear that one of my sticks of RAM had a lot of errors. Can you tell me how you had a feeling it was RAM related? Will update the answer once I confirm I no longer have the crashes

Comment: @Kadence By experience, and by looking at /var/crash. We still need to check your BIOS, as that can effect the `memtest` results. See my previous comment for the command.

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**memtest**

Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take a few hours to complete.

**BIOS**

Processor: Intel i9-9900K (16) @ 5.000GHz

Do `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and tell me the EXACT make/model # of your computer or motherboard.

**Software Updates**

Because I see "138 not upgraded" it looks like you're very behind in running `Software Updater` and keeping your system optimized.

**Update #1:**

`memtest` failed.

Will check the BIOS.

Comment: It was a bad RAM test! Not what I expected since I couldn't replicate these issues on Windows. Thank you very much

Comment: @Kadence Did you check your BIOS version? If it needs an update, we'll want to run `memtest` again after the update.